# How do you defeat the king crab in Hungry Shark?

Tags: hungry-shark

How do you kill or defeat the giant crab in the crab lair in Hungry Crab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_12138267_kill-giant-crab-hungry-shark.html) you should:

1. Swim away from the crab to avoid its attacks. It will chase you along the ocean floor.
2. Wait for the message “Attack Weak Point” to appear on the screen. A green dot will appear on the crab.
3. Ram your nose into the crab’s weak point to damage it. Continue avoiding and damaging the crab to kill it.